# NSNotificationCenter doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I do notifications like this: I have code in mainView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

CGRect view1Hrame;
view1Hrame.origin.x = 160;
view1Hrame.origin.y = 215;
view1Hrame.size = self.currenWeatherView.frame.size;

weatherViewController *view1 = [[weatherViewController alloc] initWithForecast:[[Forecast alloc] initWithForecastInCurrentLocation]];    

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:view1 selector:@selector(forecastChanged) name:@"forecastChanged" object:nil];

view1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:255 blue:0 alpha:0.06];

[currenWeatherView addSubview: view1.view];
}
```

in Forecast class:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"forecastChanged" object:nil];
```

in weatherViewController

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self       selector:@selector(forecastChanged) name:@"forecastChanged" object:nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   }
```

It does not work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Not working means?? Did you implement forecastChanged?

Comment: -(void) forecastChanged{
    
    NSLog(@"111");
    self.cityName.text        = currentForecast.cityName;
    self.currentHumidity.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentForecast.humidity] stringValue];
    self.minTemp.text         = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentForecast.minTemp] stringValue];
    self.maxTemp.text         = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentForecast.maxTemp] stringValue];
    self.currentTemp.text     = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentForecast.currentTemp] stringValue];
    
}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call notification in `weatherViewController` then you need to define this class's viewDidLoad method.

Make sure you are calling viewDidLoad of this viewController.